# Ferienhaus finde ich besser als Hotel - warum keine Artikel?

Tags: article

Grade in einem Lehrbuch gefunden:

> Ferienhaus finde ich immer besser als Hotel. (Netzwerk B1, Klett)

Wie würdet ihr den artikellosen Gebrauch hier erklären?

Comment: Hört sich umgangssprachlich an. Vermisst Du das _ein_?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Naja, auch Umgangssprache ist deutsche Sprache. Die Leute reden so. Es ist also nicht falsch, kein Ausrutscher, sondern normales Deutsch. Wieso geht das überhaupt? Was ist das Prinzip dahinter? Ähnliches Beispiel: _Brille steht dir nicht._

Comment: _"Was ist das Prinzip dahinter?"_ Verkürzung. Schriftlich würde ich das nicht verwenden.

Comment: Es gibt auch offizieller anmutende Ausnahmen für Artikellosigkeit, z.B.: Was muss Politik hier machen? Was ist hier die Aufgabe von Kirche?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: Verweis auf Nicht-Standardsprachlichkeit wäre für mich ne Billiglösung. Verkürzung vielleicht, aber Verkürzung von was?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es handelt sich jedenfalls um einen Ökonomisierungsprozess bedingt durch Werbesprache/ mediale Kommunikation oder durch die analogische Übertragung des Musters "Tätigkeit X ist besser als Tätigkeit Y" (siehe @guidot oben), wobei im letzteren Fall die Weglassung des Artikels wegen der Wortklasse "Verb" eher der kanonischen Grammatik entspricht.
Wenn du fragst, wie man das anderen Leuten erklären soll, würde ich Folgendes vorschlagen. Zwei Substantive, die eine Alternative innerhalb desselben konzeptuellen Bereichs (im Englischen sind das "frames") (Urlaubsmöglichkeit oder z.B. Transport: "Rad" oder "Auto"?) darstellen, können ohne Artikel verwendet werden.

Comment: Hat was. Aber für mich fühlt sich das hier anders an als 'mit Papier und Bleistift arbeiten' oder 'sie stand auf einmal mit Mann und Kind bei mir vor der Tür'. Ein Analogiemuster zu 'Geben ist seliger denn Nehmen' oder 'Arbeiten ist besser als zu Hause Rumliegen' klingt weitläufig an. Werbesprache ist das ganz und gar nicht, ist ein Dialog unter Bekannten und wirkt auf mich ganz natürlich... 'Ausbildung (Machen / zu machen) ist auf lange Sicht immer besser als sofort nach der Schule Geld auf die Hand (Bekommen / zu bekommen).' Dann doch verkürzte Infinitivphrasen?

Comment: Ich habe nur geschrieben, dass vielleicht Werbesprache/mediale Kommunikation die Quellen dieses Musters sind ... Wieso denn verküzte Infinitivphrasen? Es fehlt doch nur ein Artikel! Komme nicht so ganz mit...

Comment: Es geht nicht um Immobilien als Anlageobjekte, sondern darum, Urlaub zu machen, und dieses _Urlaub-Machen-in..._ wird in irgendeiner Weise mitgedacht: _In Ferienhäusern / In einem Ferienhaus Urlaub zu machen ist immer besser als ..._ Bei '_eine Brille zu tragen_' passt allerdings der Anschluss '_steht dir nicht_' nicht, das könnte eigentlich nur heißen '_passt nicht zu dir_' - was aber eine etwas andere Bedeutung hat. Ob das Muster 'wenn zwei N, dann ohne Artikel' mediensprachlich ist? Möglich, aber 'mit Pferd und Wagen' gab's sicher schon lange, da gibt's viele alte Zwillingsformeln...

Comment: Habe ich etwa was anderes geschrieben: " Zwei Substantive, die eine Alternative innerhalb desselben konzeptuellen Bereichs (im Englischen sind das "frames") (Urlaubsmöglichkeit oder z.B. Transport: "Rad" oder "Auto")? "

Comment: Du hattest geschrieben, dass die Struktur [(artikelloses) Nomen] + [(artikelloses) Nomen] sich möglicherweise aus der Werbe- oder Mediensprache herleitet (falls ich das richtig verstanden hatte). Ich bezweifle das insofern, als es Zwillingsformeln (mit Sack und Pack, bei Nacht und Nebel...) schon lange gab, bevor vor 'Werbung und Zeitungen' (! hier wieder das Muster) als Massenmedien angefangen hatten, die Sprache zu prägen.

Comment: Gut. 1. "' Dann doch verkürzte Infinitivphrasen?" Was die hier verloren haben, verstehe ich nicht. 2. "Mit Sack und Pack" etc. kannst du nicht mit deinem ursprünglichen Beispiel vergleichen, denn das sind geschlossene Redewendungen, wohingegen dein Beispiel Teil einer produktiven Konstruktion ist. Wie letztere beschrieben werden kann, habe ich schon oben erwähnt. Ansonsten bin ich mit meinem Latein ziemlich am Ende.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103912/discussion-between-ralf-joerres-and-nico).

Answer (score 6):

Meiner Auffassung nach handelt es sich um einen Fall von "Nullartikel wegen Abstraktum", vgl. [hier](https://mein-deutschbuch.de/nullartikel.html).

Es ist kein bestimmtes Ferienhaus gemeint, sondern Ferienhäuser im Allgemeinen. Es gibt zwar andere mögliche Formulierungen, aber die sind umständlicher.

Mit unbestimmten Artikel:

> Ein Ferienhaus finde ich immer besser als ein Hotel.

oder ganz anders:

> Ferienhäuser sind mir lieber als Hotels.

Außerdem: Dieser identisch strukturierte Satz verträgt gar keine Artikel:

> Schlafen ist besser als Arbeiten.

Comment: Generalisierung ("Ferienhäuser im Allgemeinen"): okay. Von wegen Abstraktum: Ja, vielleicht haben Substantive neben der Perspektive der Zähl- oder Nichtzählbarkeit auch eine Perspektive der Abstrahierbarkeit. Aber das haut hier glaube ich nicht ganz hin, es ist 'nur' die spezielle Abstraktheit, die durch Generalisierung erzeugt wird.

Comment: "Das Schlafen ist besser als das Arbeiten." Hm. Wo ist Problem?

Comment: @user unknown: Problem is sich das sagt keine Mann "Das Schlafen ist besser als das Arbeiten." - Natürlich lässt sich da was konstruieren, das wäre dann eine andere Bedeutung, und markierter ('unnormaler') wär's auch.

Answer (score 2):

Ich würde den Satz als Verkürzung von

> [Urlaub im] Ferienhaus finde ich besser als [im] Hotel

betrachten. Dabei wird der sogenannte Nullartikel verwenden, da es sich um einen nicht näher bestimmten Urlaub handelt.

Alternativ

> [Im] Ferienhaus [zu bleiben] finde ich besser, als [im] Hotel [zu bleiben].

Comment: Nullartikel oder Auslassung von *im*? Beides zusammen geht nicht.

Comment: Der Nullartikel gilt nur für den Urlaub.

Comment: Ja, es geht um 'Ferienhaus überhaupt' und 'Hotel überhaupt' und das Urlaub-Machen darin. Bleibt trotzdem die Frage: Kann man das immer so machen, wenn es um 'etwas überhaupt' geht? '_?In einem Supersommer wie 2018 ist Badeurlaub besser als Bergwanderung._ Ich weiß nicht. Wenn ja: Warum geht das? Wenn nein. warum nicht?